# Twitter streaming with multiple twitts that have same id

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hadoop-streaming, twitter-streaming-api

I collect tweets with help of [this pipeline](https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example). I tried to use some own scripts to analyse collected scripts. I found that i get multiple tweets with same id. I looked in hdfs://user/flume/tweets and saw that this multiple tweets are in stored files. So it isn't hive or oozie problem.

May it be flume problem: I made some edits in flume parameters:

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10000 //in github 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 100000 //in github 10000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 100000 //in github 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 10000 //in github 100
```

Or twitter gives this tweets? And it isn't hadoop problem?

**UPD 1**

Here is my configuration of flume:

```
# The configuration file needs to define the sources, 
# the channels and the sinks.
# Sources, channels and sinks are defined per agent, 
# in this case called 'TwitterAgent'

TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
 TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
 TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = MyKey
 TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = MyKey
 TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = MyKey
 TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = MyKey
 TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big-data , big data, analytics, bigdata, cloudera, data science, data scientiest, business intelligence, mapreduce, data warehouse, data warehousing, mahout, hbase, nosql, newsql, businessintelligence, cloudcomputing

 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://rh-hadoop-master:8020/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 100000

 TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
 TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 100000
 TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 10000
```

Here example of duplicated lines:

```
{"filter_level":"medium","retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":539321584226680833,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"timestamp_ms":"1417419260447","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"created_at":"Mon Dec 01 07:34:20 +0000 2014","favorite_count":0,"place":null,"coordinates":null,"text":"Testing Engineer, Hyderabad / Secunderabad, 2 - 5 Year Exp,Software Test Engineer , &amp;#x22;Big Data&amp;#x22;... http://t.co/DAK1ilWhM5","contributors":null,"geo":null,"entities":{"trends":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[{"expanded_url":"http://bit.ly/1ttBxPY","indices":[116,138],"display_url":"bit.ly/1ttBxPY","url":"http://t.co/DAK1ilWhM5"}],"hashtags":[{"text":"x22","indices":[89,93]},{"text":"x22","indices":[107,111]}],"user_mentions":[]},"source":"<a href=\"http://monsterindia.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">IT jobs, India<\/a>","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"retweet_count":0,"id_str":"539321584226680833","user":{"location":"India","default_profile":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"statuses_count":63546,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"0084B4","id":123537533,"following":null,"protected":false,"favourites_count":0,"profile_text_color":"333333","verified":false,"description":"Get latest job opportunities in Indian IT industry","contributors_enabled":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","name":"IT Jobs, India","profile_background_color":"C0DEED","created_at":"Tue Mar 16 11:48:44 +0000 2010","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":1245,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/790482269/sm_it1_normal.jpg","geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/88067227/IT1.jpg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/88067227/IT1.jpg","follow_request_sent":null,"url":null,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":0,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","screen_name":"tech_career","id_str":"123537533","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/790482269/sm_it1_normal.jpg","listed_count":43,"is_translator":false}}
{"filter_level":"medium","retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":539321584226680833,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"timestamp_ms":"1417419260447","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"created_at":"Mon Dec 01 07:34:20 +0000 2014","favorite_count":0,"place":null,"coordinates":null,"text":"Testing Engineer, Hyderabad / Secunderabad, 2 - 5 Year Exp,Software Test Engineer , &amp;#x22;Big Data&amp;#x22;... http://t.co/DAK1ilWhM5","contributors":null,"geo":null,"entities":{"trends":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[{"expanded_url":"http://bit.ly/1ttBxPY","indices":[116,138],"display_url":"bit.ly/1ttBxPY","url":"http://t.co/DAK1ilWhM5"}],"hashtags":[{"text":"x22","indices":[89,93]},{"text":"x22","indices":[107,111]}],"user_mentions":[]},"source":"<a href=\"http://monsterindia.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">IT jobs, India<\/a>","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"retweet_count":0,"id_str":"539321584226680833","user":{"location":"India","default_profile":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"statuses_count":63546,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"0084B4","id":123537533,"following":null,"protected":false,"favourites_count":0,"profile_text_color":"333333","verified":false,"description":"Get latest job opportunities in Indian IT industry","contributors_enabled":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","name":"IT Jobs, India","profile_background_color":"C0DEED","created_at":"Tue Mar 16 11:48:44 +0000 2010","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":1245,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/790482269/sm_it1_normal.jpg","geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/88067227/IT1.jpg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/88067227/IT1.jpg","follow_request_sent":null,"url":null,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":0,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","screen_name":"tech_career","id_str":"123537533","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/790482269/sm_it1_normal.jpg","listed_count":43,"is_translator":false}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flume does not add any kind of id to the data it is going to store. The same occurs with HDFS, it does not add any id when storing the data. They simply work together in order to move the generated data and store it.

If you are storing tweets with identical id it is because you are receiving the data with those ids, or you are interpreting the data in the wrong way.

Being said that, maybe you could add some examples to your question by editing it.

Comment: In stored files(from flume) I can see multiple lines with same text.

Comment: Can you add all the Flume configuration to the question, please? In addition, can you share with us a couple of those replicated lines you comment, please?

Comment: Done. I added my flume configuration and duplicated lines.

Comment: My bet was a same tweet was matching two keywords, but I can only find "big data" within the tweet you printed... Can you make a test by configuring a unique keyword? Just to confirm even in that case you are replicating the tweet in HDFS.

Comment: I very beginning of this streaming i made some test tweets with multiple hashtags. But every  time i got only one tweet in Hive tables.